# Why doesn't php while loop scan through x #of times and include x # of files?

Tags: php, while-loop, php-include

I have some code I use to create emails based on form inputs. One of the first inputs, a number input named "**nosections**" is used to control how many sections are in the email. Then there are "**sectionblock**" inputs (e.g. **sectionblock1**, **sectionblock2**) that control which content blocks go in each section of the email.

I wanted to use a while loop that would run through the values for each section until hitting the "nosections" value, pulling the blocks for each section as it ran through...however, it only seems to include the first sectionblock (i.e. sectionblock1).

For example, say the following is true:

- $nosections = 3
- $sectionblock1 = "tastingclassblock"
- $sectionblock2 = "rrtastings"
- $sectionblock3 = "winespecials"

Can someone tell me why if I run the above, it only includes the block of code for tastingclassblock, and not also the blocks for rrtastings and winespecials?

```
<?php 
$i=1; 

while ($i <= $nosections):
    if(${'sectionblock'.$i} == 'weekendtasting'):
        include('plaintext/weekend-tastings/weekend-tasting.php');
    elseif(${'sectionblock'.$i} == 'tastingclassblock'):
        include('plaintext/special-classes/tasting-class-code.php');
    elseif(${'sectionblock'.$i} == 'rrtastings'):
        include('plaintext/resroomtastings/tasting-class-code.php');
    elseif(${'sectionblock'.$i} == 'weeklyad'):
        include('plaintext/weekly-ad/weeklyad.php');
    elseif(${'sectionblock'.$i} == 'customerappreciation'):
        include('plaintext/customer-appreciation/customer-appreciation.php');
    elseif(${'sectionblock'.$i} == 'giftsets'):
        include('plaintext/holiday-giftsets/gift-sets-code.php');
    elseif(${'sectionblock'.$i} == 'winespecials'):
        include('plaintext/winespecials/wine-specials.php');
    elseif(${'sectionblock'.$i} == 'spiritspecials'):
        include('plaintext/spiritspecials/spirit-specials.php');
    elseif(${'sectionblock'.$i} == 'featuredfood'):
        include('plaintext/featured-foodgroup/featured-food-group.php');
    elseif(${'sectionblock'.$i} == 'featuredrecipe'):
        include('plaintext/featured-recipe/featured-recipe.php');
    endif;

$i++;
endwhile; ?>
```

Comment: see if error reporting picks up anything http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php

Comment: It's been on the whole time I've been trying to get this working, and I'm not getting any errors.

Answer (score 1):

Tested your code locally and everything runs fine. First you should check if `$nosections` is really getting the value of `3`. Second you should check for any mistakes with includes, because locally i just echo'ed them, but if you'r getting any error, it may be because of wrong include therefore the while-loop to get stopped. Check also for errors after `include('plaintext/special-classes/tasting-class-code.php');` gets included. Best regards.

Comment: Thanks, Artley. $nosections is definitely getting the correct value because there's other code based on that value that is working correctly. I have error reporting turned on and I'm not receiving any errors. And the file locations are correct...I copied them from the previous, more convoluted method I was using to perform this task (from a file in the same directory).

This one has me stumped.

Comment: Can you try to debug it manually? Let's say echo $nosections before the if-statement, than replace the include with echo. Sometimes mistakes happen and it may get it's value null-ed or changed in other class/method etc.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions, Artley. Just realized the error was a separate while loop in some of the included files with variable $i. I changed the variable on this one to $s and everything seems to be working now. I appreciate your time and responses, though.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for wasting all of your time. I just realized what the issue is. On several of the modules I was trying to include, I was also running while loops with the variable $i. So, $i was being inflated past the $nosections number while running those loops. I changed the variable name to $s and everything seems to be working.

Thank you for your kind responses.